# A sum that scales as the square root of the summands

Tags: summation

Is there some (edit! analytic) expression $h(x)$ such that the sum $$\sum_{i=1}^n h(i)$$ scales as $O\left(n^\frac{1}{2}\right)$?

Regarding the (40) comments under Sabyasachi's accepted answer: When you run a sum like $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{c\sqrt{x}}$ in WolframAlpha, the output should be interpreted as HarmonicNumber[n,1/2] (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HarmonicNumber.html), where $r = \frac{1}{2}$ is the order of the harmonic number.  $H_n^{\frac{1}{2}} \neq \sqrt{H_n}$!  It's rather surprising that Sabyasachi and I got as far as we did before he noticed the error.

Comment: what do you mean "analytic". Does $\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}$ work for you?

Comment: @Sabyasachi Yes, that would work for me, I just don't understand how to think about the Harmonic number in the sum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While 5xum's answer of the sum *being* $\sqrt{x}$ is certainly great, here is something easier to spot. Let $f(x)=\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}$. This can be bounded by the integral. The sum is $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$. Test results.

For $n=100$, sum is $9.24$
For n=1000, sum is $30.88$
For n=10000, sum is $99.26$

Pretty right?

---

**Proof:**

Obviously if $f$ is a monotonically decreasing function

$$\sum_{i=1}^nf(i) \lt \int_1^{n+1}f(x)\,dx$$

Similarly

$$\sum_{i=2}^nf(i)\gt\int_1^nf(x)\,dx()$$

or

$$\sum_{i=1}^nf(i)\gt f(1)+\int_1^nf(x)\,dx$$

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ and we are done.

Comment: Doesn't a function of the form $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{c\sqrt{x}}$ scale as $\frac{H_n^{\frac{1}{2}}}{c}$ where $H_n$ is the Harmonic number of $n$?

Comment: @Mantrissa you can check by bounding with the integral. You meant [generalized harmonic number](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HarmonicNumber.html)

Comment: Just ask wolfram alpha to do that sum for you. or I can right a proof?

Comment: Here's the WolframAlpha result: http://goo.gl/HbmbX5

Comment: So can we say this scales as $O(n^\frac{1}{2})$?  $H_n$ blows up to infinity as $n \to \infty$ right?  I'm not saying your wrong, just that this is a point of confusion for me.

Comment: @Mantrissa yes. If the actual sums don't satisfy you I can prove that the sum lies between $\sqrt{x+1} -1$ and $\sqrt{x} - 1$. good enough?

Comment: Can we actually say something about the value of the smallest summand?  And if you have a proof for that bound, that would be really neat.

Comment: @Mantrissa yes we can say. that sum always lies between those two limits for *any* $n\gt 1$.

Comment: @Mantrissa even $\sqrt{n}$ blows up to $\infty$ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: Just for the record, $H_n$ is $\Theta(\log(n))$

Comment: Ah, I see now why you set $c = 2$ for $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{c\sqrt{x}}$.  Nice.

Comment: @Mantrissa thanks. :D any other constant would work though, since $\Theta(c\sqrt{x}) = \Theta(\sqrt{x})$

Comment: $c=2$ just makes it as close to $\sqrt{x}$ as possible(at least for me)

Comment: Well, I meant that the bounds look pretty with $c = 2$ (oddly WolframAlpha times out with this integral).

Comment: You're right that since $H_n \approx \Theta(\log(n))$ that we already have $O(n^\frac{1}{2})$ scaling.  Can we say however that we have $\Theta(log(n)^\frac{1}{2})$ scaling for $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{c\sqrt{x}}$?

Comment: @Mantrissa w|a is close to intelligent, not "human intelligent". We still have creativity. ;)

Comment: Yes, however both are larger than $\Theta(\sqrt{log(n)})$?

Comment: @Mantrissa $\Theta(\log(n)^{1/2}) \lt \Theta(n^{1/2})$ And the summation here is *always* $\Theta(x^{1/2})$ no matter what $c$. To understand, see that we $c$ is a constant factor that can come out of the summation.

Comment: yes both are larger. typo

Comment: You mean that the sum here always has $\Theta(\log(n)^{1/2})$ and $O(n^\frac{1}{2})$ asymptotic scaling, or am I confused?

Comment: @Mantrissa the sum always has $\Theta(n^{1/2})$ scaling, which is $\Omega(\log(n)^{1/2})$

Comment: do you get it now?

Comment: $\Theta(n^{1/2})$ makes sense, since we know the sum is within a small constant of this.  We also know that the floor is $\Omega(\log(n)^{1/2})$ within a constant.  So this makes sense.  I'm just unsure why we can't tighten Big Theta here to $\log(n)^{1/2}$?

Comment: @Mantrissa $g(x)=\Theta(f(x))$ implies that $$cf(x)\lt g(x) \lt df(x)$$ for some $c,d\gt0$ once $x$ gets sufficiently large. Here you want to make $\sqrt{n} = \Theta(\log(n)^{1/2})$ but the square root function always grows faster than the logarithm, and so, the lower bound never gets satisfied, no matter what $c$

Comment: Yup, makes sense. :)

Comment: We can't have Big Theta, g(x) = Big Omega, f(x)?

Comment: @Mantrissa what are your g and f?

Comment: This is guaranteed to be a stupid question, but why can't we say that, given: $cf(x)\lt g(x) \lt df(x)$, we can set $g(x) = f(x) = \sqrt{n} = \log(n)^{1/2}$?

Comment: @Mantrissa if *both* $f$ and $g$ are $\sqrt{n}$ then where does your $\log$ come in. taking both $g$ and $f$ to be the same would make $\sqrt{x}=\Theta(\sqrt{x})$. Trivial.

Comment: I made a typo, I meant both are $\log(n)^{1/2}$?

Comment: @Mantrissa yes. If both $f$ and $g$ are $\log(n)^{1/2}$ then we can write $g=\Theta(f)$. But you seem to have wandered off, how does this relate to the summation?

Comment: Well, we have an exact result for the summation, right?  And this exact result is $H_n^\frac{1}{2}$.  Now, we also know that the sum is within a small constant factor of $n^\frac{1}{2}$.  So what's confusing to me is why we can't set Big Theta to the more precise expression for the sum's scaling $log(n)^\frac{1}{2}$  (given that $H_n \approx log(n)$)?

Comment: @Mantrissa $H_n^{1/2} \ne \sqrt{H_n}$. The "exponent" of half is merely a notation. Btw, the second part is right. $H_n \approx \log(n) +\gamma$ to be more precise.

Comment: Oh, yikes yikes, its the order of the harmonic number.  Everything makes sense now, I'm really glad you caught that!  And the order doesn't seem like it would matter for the approximation $H_n \approx \log(n) +\gamma$ does it?

Comment: @Mantrissa for that approximation, the order is *fixed* to be $1$

Comment: I see, so we can't actually use that approximation where we have order $\frac{1}{2}$ as we do here.

Comment: @Mantrissa no we can't. But we don't need to. $H_n^c$ can be derived using this same integral method. Euler's approximation of $H_n$ is just a special case of this(with $c=1$)

Comment: Ok, that's clear.  Sorry about this, I tripped up on the notation.  Thanks for your extensive help.

Comment: If you integrate $1/x$ you get $\log(x)$. Same bounds as this. Using it we can say that $\log(n+1)\lt H_n \lt \log(n) + 1$. $\gamma$ is a tighter bound than $1$

Comment: @Mantrissa happily. :)

Answer (score 1):

The function $h(k)=\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k-1}=\frac1{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k-1}}$ satisfies
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nh(k)=\sqrt{n}\tag{1}
$$

---

**Analysis of $\ \displaystyle\mathbf{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{k}}}\,$:**

Since $2\sqrt{k}\le\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}\le2\sqrt{k+1}$, we have
$$
\frac12\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}}\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}\le\frac12\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{k}}\tag{2}
$$
Since $\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}=\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}\right)\\
&=\sqrt{n+1}-1\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Combining $(2)$ and $(3)$ yields
$$
2\sqrt{n+1}-2\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{k}}\le2\sqrt{n}-1\tag{4}
$$
Thus,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{k}}=\Theta\left(\sqrt{n}\right)\tag{5}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Why not? Take $h(1) = 1$, then define $$h(n) = n^{\frac12} - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}h(i).$$

Then $$\sum_{i=1}^n h(i) = h(n) + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}h(i)  = n^{\frac12} - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}h(i)+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}h(i)=n^{\frac12}$$

This series is not just $O\left(n^\frac12\right)$, it *is* $n^\frac12$

Comment: Ah shoot, I meant - is there an example of an analytic expression $h(x)$ that has this property?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: It was no trouble. I expected my answer was not what you needed, but I added it as a semi-amusing example which technically answers the question you asked. It is still an illustration how you can make a sequence with an arbitrary value $\sum_{i=1}^nh(i)=a_i$ for any collection of values $a_i$. Just replace $n^{\frac12}$ with $a_i$ in my argument.

Comment: Haha, thank you, I appreciate it. :)

Comment: You seem to have overlooked the simplification $h(x) = \sqrt{x} - \sqrt{x-1}$.

Comment: @Hurkyl Oh snap!

Comment: @Hurkyl If I can ask, how did you find that?

Comment: Because you already know the value of $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} h(i)$. :)

Comment: @Hurkyl Hah, nice.

Comment: @Hurkyl oh my god. you post that answer, and I swear I will upvote it.